# New nodejs app deployed on heroku app doesn't find my libs

Tags: javascript, node.js, heroku, module

I'm trying to deploy a node.js app on `heroku` (btw it is my first time that I do that).

The same module that works on dev doesn't on testing (as usuall I would like to say) because the directory is not found.

This is the impliceted piece of code:

```
const PersistanceManager = require( `@mainlib/PersistanceManager` );
```

Where `@mainlib` is a variable into my package.json

```
    "@mainlib": "lib/"
```

basically it is pointing to `lib` that is in the root directory.
I looked around but I found thousands of answer that didn't work for me.

Answer (score 0):

We have this problem because we using a with **backslash**, that is good on Windows, instead of **fowardslash** that it is what heroku expects when you working on it.